# Storing long query in variant datatype in Excel

Tags: sql, vba

I have to store long queries (>255 characters) in a variable with type variant to utilize it to extract data from DB. But the variable doesn't contain even close to 255 characters.

Is there a way I can save these long queries and utilize it for extraction from DB?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what database you are using.

In general it is not good idea to implement the DB logic in application, especially in case of such complex (long) queries.

Sorry for not answering your question directly, but I would suggest you to consider to create Views or Stored Procedures (or similar, depending on your SQL server) to simplify the application side.

Comment: Sorry not providing full information. We are access DB2 database. we are using this in excel VBA for data extraction and verification using VBA.

Comment: Show me omitted version of your SQL string assignment to a Variant variable.